# Transferring localization from PHP to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, localization

I have localization written for my wabsite, in PHP. Since I'm also working with Javascript (jQuery), to dynamically add some tags, I have problems with localization.

For example: I add comments dynamically. The user can click "Show more comments", to show the next page of comments. If all comments are shown, the text changes to "All comments displayed". But this way, nothing is localized, because it's only using Javascript.

How could I transfer the localization to javascript? My current idea is to create a PHP script, that would accept a GET variable, for example "all-comments". Then it would search for the localized version of that, and return a JSON string. Is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: How are you currently doing it?

Comment: Well, currently all the strings in Javascript are outputted in English, there is no JS Localization yet.

Comment: "I have localization written for my wabsite, in PHP." HOW.

Comment: Oh, I have a PHP file for every language. In each file I define a variable: `$l = new Language('en');` then, I add each string to translate. For example: `$l->addWord('welcome_msg', 'Welcome to my website!');`. Then, when I have to echo the string, I just call it: `echo $l->welcome_msg;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to approach this.

- If you want to have all localization handled in server-side PHP logic, you could have all calls that change DOM content pull that new localized content from the server (via AJAX).
- Alternatively, if you don't want server calls but still want all localization generated via PHP, you could pre-populate a javascript object with a set of localizations to use for whatever content might need to be displayed on that page.
- If you want to keep javascript localizations within javascript, you could have localized js files on the server (or at least have localized javascript language files that for example contain a javascript object with all localizations).